# Sonar marca "Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly" en getters y setters automáticos para Timestamp y List

Tags: java, spring, sonar

Como puedo poner los getter y setter para estas opciones TimeStamp y List, para que no me salga este mensaje en sonar.

Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly

Mutable objects are those whose state can be changed. For instance, an array is mutable, but a String is not. Mutable class members should never be returned to a caller or accepted and stored directly. Doing so leaves you vulnerable to unexpected changes in your class state.

```
/**
     * @return the fecmoc
     */
    public Timestamp getFecmoc() {
        return fecmoc;

}
    /**
     * @param fecmoc the fecmoc to set
     */
    public void setFecmoc(Timestamp fecmoc) {
        this.fecmoc = fecmoc;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema, lo primero es entenderlo: En Java existen ciertos tipos o clases de datos que usamos comúnmente para guardar información:

- `String` y `char`/`Char` para texto
- `boolean`/`Boolean`
- `int`, `long`, `double`... y sus *wrappers* para números, además de  `BigDecimal` o `BigInteger`.

Todas estas clases tienen en común que son **inmutables**. Si tienes una variable o un atributo de este tipo, la única manera de cambiar la información guardada es crear una nueva instancia y asignarla. No existe algo como

```
String s = "texto";
s.setValue("text"); //no hay modo de modificar el valor de la instancia
```

Las clases `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Timestamp` no son inmutables (y esto es un defecto de diseño, por eso desde Java 8 se desaconseja su uso en favor de las clases del paquete `java.time`).

Ahora imagina este escenario: Pides la fecha de nacimiento de un usuario para comprobar que es mayor que edad, con una lógica así:

```
void setBirthDate(Timestamp bdate) {
   if (isOverEighteen(bdate) {
     this.birthDate = bdate;
   } else {
     throw TooYoungException(bdate);
   }
}
```

Ahora podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
Timestamp d = new Timestamp(90,11,1,0,0,0) //1990, Octubre, 1 ... sí, así de horrible funciona
usuario.setBirthDate(d); //pasa la comprobación
d.setYear(111); //1900 + 111 = 2011, no me cansaré de decir que es una API horrible
```

Ahora resulta que la fecha guardada en el usuario es 1 de Octubre de 2011, lo que no cumple los requerimientos.

Para protegerse de este cambio, IntelliJ pide que hagas una copia del valor y te quedes con esa copia "privada", de ese modo nadie podrá modificarla:

```
void setBirthDate(Timestamp bdate) {
   Timestamp tempDate= bdate.clone();
   if (isOverEighteen(tempDate) {
     this.birthDate = tempDate;
   } else {
     throw TooYoungException(tempDate);
   }
}
```

Y del mismo modo, que entregues siempre una copia a quien la pida, nunca el original:

```
public Timestamp getBirthDate() {
    return this.birthDate.clone();
}
```

Ahora bien, si quieres realmente evitar problemas, mi recomendación es que **no uses NUNCA la clase `java.util.Date`**, usa `java.time.LocalDate`, `java.time.LocalDateTime` o `java.time.Instant`, según tus necesidades. Si estás manteniendo una aplicación anterior a Java 8, te recomiendo el uso de `JodaTime`.

Lo mismo pasa con clases como ArrayList, siempre se puede hacer algo como:

```
usuario.setEmails(new ArrayList<>());
usuario.getEmails().add("email@inventado.com");
```

a menos que la lista sea inmutable:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(list); //devuelve una copia inmodificable
```